# How to get [Int] instead of [[Int]] Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, lambda, record

I am a newbie to Haskell functional programming. I've studied lambda functions, lists,types, record syntax, and functors from several sources like [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)  a book called *Get Programming With Haskell*. I get some idea of how functions works and essentials of functional programming. At this point, I stuck at the point where I need to use list of records inside lamda functions which is a parameter of a map function.

[Here](https://replit.com/@mahmutsalman/MyProject#Main.hs) I share runable code.

I have a **record** of Person

```
data Person = Person
 {name :: Name
 ,lastname :: LastName
 ,personId :: Int
 ,sex :: Int
 ,parentList ::  [Int]
 ,childList :: [Int]
 ,siblingList :: [Int]
 }
 deriving (Show,Typeable,Data,Eq)
```

**1-** I have a **getParentListPerson**  :: Person-> [Person] -> [Person] function that returns parents of a given Person using [Person] list. (I hold every person in *everybody :: [Person]* )

```
getParentListPerson :: Person-> [Person] -> [Person]
getParentListPerson p ps = filter((\px -> elem (personId p) (childList px))) ps
```

**2-** And **isCousen function** that returns true if the first parameter and the second parameter is cousens.*(where first person's one of parents should be in the siblingList of second person's one of parents)*

```
isCousen :: Person -> Person -> Bool
isCousen p1 p2 =any f (parentList p1)
        where f= (\x -> elem x $ map func2 $ func3 p2 everybody):([Int]->Bool)
              func2 = (\y -> (siblingList y))::(Person->[Int])
              func3 = (\z k-> getParentListPerson z k)::(Person->[Person]->[Person])
```

Here what I am trying to do is to create a **lambda function f** ***that takes parentList ([Int])***
and finds any matching person.

1. **f** :: [Int]->Bool
2. **funcs2** :: Person -> [Int].
3. **func3** :: Person -> [Person ] -> [Person].

When I run this I get this error:
*(As far as I understand although I want to give a **Person** to func2 using **map** in where clause I cannot achive. I know that map takes a function and a list.So I **assume** *func3 cannot return [Person]*.So the problem should be in the getParentListPerson function)*

```
app\Main.hs:89:24: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Int' with `[Int]'
      Expected type: [[Int]]
        Actual type: [Int]
    * In the second argument of `any', namely `(parentList p1)'
      In the expression: any f (parentList p1)
      In an equation for `isCousen':
          isCousen p1 p2
            = any f (parentList p1)
            where
                f = (\ x -> elem x <$> concatMap func2 <$> func3 p2 everybody) ::
                      ([Int] -> Bool)
                func2 = (\ y -> (siblingList y)) :: (Person -> [Int])
                func3
                  = (\ z k -> getParentListPerson z k) ::
                      (Person -> [Person] -> [Person])
   |
89 | isCousen p1 p2 =any f (parentList p1)
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It says that I am giving [Int] where the expected parameter should be [[Int]]. I am a bit lost. Any help would be appreciated.
I suspect that I may use **map** function and **lambda functions** incorrectly but *I did what I can.* They seem correct from my knowledge

Comment: It's always good to write type signatures for all your intermediate functions (in this case `f`, `func2`, and `func3`) if you cannot understand the type errors you get. Then the compiler can show you more accurately where things are going wrong.

Comment: I did what you have mentioned and sadly got a bunch of errors.

Comment: You marked all your functions with non-function types, so you get a type error. You can't write `(\y -> ...) :: [Int]` since a function is not a list.

Comment: I corrected it as you said. Thank you @chi. Although I get clearer errors, still I am trying to understand these errors.

Comment: You say that `func2` should get a `Person` as argument, but the type you give `func2` says that it takes a `[Person]` (list of persons) as argument. `map func2` would take `[Person]` as argument, but here you should just write the type for a `func2` without the `map`.

Comment: You are right . I just corrected it a few seconds ago. @Noughtmare

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps you need to use `concatMap` instead of `map`: the function you pass to `map` already produces a list, so you you end up with a list-of-lists.

Comment: I've looked at its definition of concatMap. It has the right definition but when I try it I get same error @chi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `func2` returns a list which means that `map func2` returns a list of lists. What you want to probably do is to concatenate these together. Thus change:

```
elem x $ map func2 $ func3 p2 everybody
```

into:

```
elem x $ concat $ map func2 $ func3 p2 everybody
```

There's also a combination of `concat` and `map` namely `concatMap` so you can simplify it into:

```
elem x $ concatMap func2 $ func3 p2 everybody
```

It seems that you have switched to this according to comment by chi which is reflected in the error message though you have still left the original code unchanged. The problem with this appears to be that you have also replaced every `$` with `<$>` which is not correct because `<$>` does the same thing as `map`. If you want to use `<$>` you can replace `map` with it like so:

```
elem x $ concat $ func2 <$> func3 p2 everybody
```

Then I can also note how some of your functions could be simplified somewhat (even though you didn't ask about that). You don't need to use all or any of these simplifications but you might at least consider them.

In the following functions you use lambda.

```
func2 = (\y -> (siblingList y))
func3 = (\z k-> getParentListPerson z k)
```

Since the lambda is the entire expression you can just use normal function syntax for these instead of lambda like so:

```
func2 y = siblingList y
func3 z k = getParentListPerson z k
```

But now you can also notice that these do nothing but apply arguments to a function so they're equivalent to:

```
func2 = siblingList
func3 = getParentListPerson
```

But since now we can see that `func2` and `func3` are basically just function aliases we can just remove them and substitute `siblingList` and `getParentListPerson` for them in the definition of `f` like so:

```
f = (\x -> elem x $ concatMap siblingList $ getParentListPerson p2 everybody)
```

Here you can also remove the lambda:

```
f x = elem x $ concatMap siblingList $ getParentListPerson p2 everybody
```

You could also simplify `getParentListPerson` a little bit in somewhat similar manner. Alternatively, you could also instead use `parentList` though you'd then need to convert each `Int` into `Person`.

Btw, the word "Cousin" is misspelled in the function name `isCousen`.